# Maximum Likelihood Estimate for power law in R given distribution (instead of samples)

Tags: r, model-fitting, mle, power-law

I have a dataframe with x-y values representing values and their counts, e.g. (1, 1000), (2, 100), (3, 10), etc. I would like to fit a power law to this distribution using MLE.

I could use the power.law.fit or poweRlaw libraries, but it appears that these libraries take in specific samples for data instead of x-y values representing values and their counts.

Is there any other library that might do the job? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `poweRlaw` package - it's just a bit clunky. Simply expand your values and counts into a single vector, e.g.

```
dd = data.frame(x=1:3, counts = 3:1)
x = rep(dd$x, dd$counts)
library(poweRlaw)
m = displ$new(x)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!